# list full of sentences and i need to slice and count a word from rest of list

Tags: python, list, slice

I need to slice a word from from a sentence in a list and then cound how many times this word has been used in a file.  I started by reading the file in a list.  This put a whole sentence into one position of a list.  Im looking to slice the sentence from character 7 - 14, cutting the word i need out and then counting how many times that word has been used in the whole file or rest of the list! need help!

Comment: can you show us the code of what you've already done?

Answer (score 0):

> Im looking to slice the sentence from character 7 - 14

You should look at [string slicing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation). To get the characters in a string from position 7 (inclusive) to 14 (exclusive):

```
example = "this is an example string"
what_you_want = example[7:14]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split method to turn a sentence into a list of words like this:

```
sentence = "this is a sentence"
setence_list = sentence.split(" ")
```

turns our sentence into

```
['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence']
```

Which allows you to index the sentence with something like:   list[2]

You can essentially do the same thing with the file and then use a for loop to count how many times the word happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("file.txt","r")
substring = file.readline()[6:14]
print(file.read().replace("\n"," ").split(" ").count(substring+1))
```